# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory due to imported json on tsc:watch

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a script that imports data stored in json file which is 10MB (it contains an array of several thousand objects). So it is a large file, but not huge in terms of available PC memory.

When I run `tsc:watch` it fails with the `Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

As suggested in some existing answers I tried increasing the memory with `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` or even 16GB, but it still failed.

Is there any smart and elegant way to solve this problem without having to swap files in the `dist` folder? The scrip does work with the file, it just does not compile with `tsc:watch`.